# Compute $\int _{\frac{4}{5}}^2\:f^{-1}\left(x\right)dx$ where $f\left(x\right)=\frac{-x^3+2x^2-5x+8}{x^2+4},\:x\in \mathbb{R}$ is bijection.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, inverse, inverse-function

We have to compute $\int _{\frac{4}{5}}^2\:f^{-1}\left(x\right)dx$  where $f\left(x\right)=\frac{-x^3+2x^2-5x+8}{x^2+4},\:x\in \mathbb{R}$ is an bijective function.

What we can extract from bijective information?

---

**EDIT :** Based on Answers, I tried to Plot this

[image]

Comment: If $f$ was not bijective, you would not be able to define its inverse uniquely. That's the point of telling you it is bijective. Are you doing this problem by hand or with a computer software like Mathematica?

Comment: by hand and after verify with a computer software, but the purpose is to understand, not to solve because don't motivate me if I know the result and don't understand problem...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: If the function bijective, you can draw the function as I drew below

Step 1: Find $a$  and $b$

$f(a)=\frac{4}{5} $

$f(b)=2 $

And compute $B=\int _{a}^b\:f\left(x\right)dx$

[image]

Step 2:

Compute rectangle area of C and compute $B-C$

[image]

Step 3:

$A=\int _{\frac{4}{5}}^2\:f^{-1}\left(x\right)dx$

$A+B-C$ is also a rectangle  .

Comment: I think it is better to draw pictures with a decreasing function, since the given $f(x)$ is decreasing on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes İt could be .Thanks for comment. I just wanted to give a hint  how to approach for such problems.

Comment: how help me B and C? is my first time when I meet this kind of integral and I don't understand... think you have the patience to explain me ... please?

Comment: nice work. it makes no difference whether you draw it increasing or decreasing. what counts is that $f$ is 1-1 in that segment. don't pay any heed to jack's comment

Comment: @abel how help me if I know who is B and C? I suppose we need to find B and C...

Comment: @lucas, i am doing the problem. i will post it either as a comment or a post in a few minutes.

Answer (score 5):

You may notice that $f(x)$ is a decreasing function on the interval $[0,1]$ and $f(0)=2,\,f(1)=\frac{4}{5}$, from which it follows that (just look at the picture below to figure it out):
$$ \int_{\frac{4}{5}}^{2}f^{-1}(x)\,dx = -\frac{4}{5}+\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx=\color{red}{\frac{7}{10}+\log 2-\frac{\log 5}{2}}\tag{1}$$
where the last result follows from polynomial division.

[image]

Comment: how we obtain $\int _0^1\:f\left(x\right)dx$?

Comment: @Lucas: did you draw a picture as suggested? Thanks to mathlover, you can find it below.

Comment: why you have $ \int_{2}^{\frac{4}{5}}f^{-1}(x)\,dx$ ? and not $\int _{\frac{4}{5}}^2$ ?

Comment: @Lucas: that was just a typo, now fixing.

Comment: this work if we make substitution?

Comment: @Lucas: a substitution $x=f(t)$ followed by integration by parts works just fine.

Comment: how did you obtain -4/5 ?

Comment: @Lucas: draw that picture, please. $f(x)$ decreases from $2$ to $\frac{4}{5}$ on $[0,1]$. To compute that integral, we just need to compute the integral of $f(x)$ over $[0,1]$ then subtract the area of a rectangle (guess which one).

Comment: tell me if is correct how I drew..

Comment: @Lucas: I have just added a picture. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(u)=x$, then integration by parts gives
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{4/5}^2f^{-1}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_1^0u\,\mathrm{d}f(u)\\
&=-\int_0^1u\,\mathrm{d}f(u)\\
&=-\left[uf(u)\vphantom{\int}\right]_0^1+\int_0^1f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-\frac45+\int_0^1\frac{-u^3+2u^2-5u+8}{u^2+4}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-\frac45+\int_0^1\frac{2u^2+8}{u^2+4}\,\mathrm{d}u-\int_0^1\frac{u^2+5}{u^2+4}u\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac65-\frac12\int_4^5\frac{v+1}v\,\mathrm{d}v\\
&=\frac7{10}-\frac12\log\left(\frac54\right)
\end{align}
$$
where $v=u^2+4$.

Answer (score 1):

draw a graph of $y = f(x).$  you will see that it has $y$-intercept at $(0,1)$ and has a point $(1,4/5).$  the area you are after is the triangular region bounded by $x = 0$ on the left, by $y = \frac 45$ at the bottom and $y = f(x)$ like a hypotenuse. the area $$\int_{4/5}^2 x\,dy$$ is like cutting the triangle in slices/strips parallel to the $x-$ axis. now, we can find the same area by slicing parallel to the $y$-axis. this way we get the area to be $$ \int_0^1\left(y - \frac 45\right)\, dx$$

this is what Mathlover was trying to show you with a picture. hope this is of some use to you.

Comment: is not $ \int_0^1\left(x - \frac 45\right)\, dx$ ?

Comment: @Lucas,  the strips are parallel to the $y-axis and the width of the strip is $dx.$  i have a class to go to. i will be back in an hour.